# Mirror files between production and development servers

Tags: synchronization, development-environment, rsync, mirroring

What would be the best tool to use for OSX to mirror files from development server to production server?

I have tried rsync with `-av` options from localhost to remote server, but it seems to be really slow. I have also tried FreeFileSync. On Windows I have Create Syncronicity, which is very good software in my opinion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

rsync is *usually* one of the fastest ways to synchronize files over network, but it won't compress files unless you specify the `-z` option. That should improve the transfer of text files (HTML, CSS, JS) quite a lot. It won't affect binary files such as JPG or PNG much though since they're not easily compressed.

Also try `--stats` to get some insights into the actual transfer speeds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is rsync comparing content of the files which will be synced or just dates those are when modified?

Comment: @lingo Yes, rsync compares content in a [clever way](https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/). Using the `-a` option it preserves basically everything else as well: file permissions, ownership, dates etc.